# What is this combinator?

Tags: javascript, combinators

I used a combinator to calculate the average of a list of numbers...

`const myCombinator = f => g => h => x => f(g(x))(h(x));`

I could then use it like...

```
const div = a => b => a/b;
const sum = a => a.reduce((a, n) => a + n, 0);
const length = a => a.length();

const average = myCombinator(div)(sum)(length);

console.log(average([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

However, I'm not sure which combinator this is from a list like... http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/combinator/birds.html

I was told initially that it's a Blackbird combinator but I don't think that is the case? Is that correct?

Is it a "named" combinator? If so, do you know which one it is?

**From the comments**

Blackbird is defined like... `blackbird :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d`

However, I think my function is doing like...

`myCombinator :: (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> d`

i.e. it returns a function that takes an `a` and returns a `d`. `a` is passed into two functions which creates `b` and `c`. They are then passed into a function that returns `d`.

**After the above comment**

I found it! From [@evolutionxbox link](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-birds/blob/master/README.md) I found the `Starling_` combinator...

`starling_ :: (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> d`

Which is exactly what I had written above :D

Comment: https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-birds/blob/master/README.md#blackbird--c---d---a---b---c---a---b---d It does look like the blackbird combinator ... maybe

Comment: @evolutionxbox would you be able to deconstruct it for me as I've been looking at it for ages and I can't see how it fits the pattern. Haha :D `blackbird :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d`

Comment: `x` (the array) is being passed to `sum` and `length` separately. The outputs of those are then passed into the converge function `div`. Which gives you the final output. So I am more convinced that it's the blackbird.

Comment: @evolutionxbox my head gets tied in knots every time I try to evaluate this. I think the difference here is that I have a function with one input that then gets passed into two functions before composing with a third. Whereas the Blackbird has two inputs that get passed into one composed function that then gets composed with a second.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I found a better fit, the `Starling_` combinator is definitely doing what I am doing :D Thanks for the link though :D

Comment: That's it! Consider adding the answer to your question? You found it ;)

Comment: The blackbird pipes a function with 2 inputs to a function with 1 input. So your combinator is not a blackbird. I'd recommend checking out [this video](https://youtu.be/seVSlKazsNk) for more information about the blackbird, and combinators in general.

Comment: @3limin4t0r haha, thanks for the link. I actually watched that for the first time earlier today. Great minds think alike. Hehe 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful link from @evolutionxbox I was able to find the `Starling_` combinator which is defined as...

`starling_ :: (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> d`

In my case...

- `a -> b` is my `sum` function that takes the array and returns a number.
- `a -> c` is my `length` function that takes the array and return a number.
- `b -> c -> d` is my `div` function that takes two numbers and divides them.

This is the first time I feel like I've understood combinators properly now. :)

Thanks for the help :)